# How to clone elements for cakephp elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cakephp

I have made a template (of a set of bunch of html tags which it might be textarea or types of inputs) I want to clone the template. I want to rename the 'name' and 'id' attributes of each element just by replacing the number while cloning. I preffer to use regex in order to do that.

I want to loop through all Html elements and rename the attributes of new elements. e.g.

```
id="extrainfofiles-0-extrainfofile-extra-info-file-type-id"
for="extrainfofiles-0-extrainfofile-extra-info-file-type-id"
name="ExtraInfoFiles[0][ExtraInfoFile][extra_info_file_type_id]"
```

To:

```
id="extrainfofiles--566345634-extrainfofile-extra-info-file-type-id"
for="extrainfofiles--566345634-extrainfofile-extra-info-file-type-id"
name="ExtraInfoFiles[-566345634][ExtraInfoFile][extra_info_file_type_id]"
```

Any help please.

Here is JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/isaacrajaei/133ko1un/

Comment: For this you need to create your html template through AJAX request.Means when you click on add another file ,send a ajax request to server and load your .ctp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Add A File
 */
$('#extrainfo-files').on('click', '.extrafile-add', function(){

    // Create the new row
    var $fileList = $('.file-list-extrainfo');
    var $template = $('.extrainfo-file-template').clone();

    var rowId = '-' + (new Date).getTime();
    $template.removeClass('extrainfo-file-template hide').attr('data-id', rowId);

    // Append the new row to the list
    $template.appendTo($fileList);

    // Rename the attributes 
    var $row = $('.file-row[data-id="' + rowId + '"]');
    updateElements($row.selector, 0, rowId);

});


function updateElements(el, from, to)
    {
        $(el).find('[name*="['+from+']"], [id*="-'+from+'-"], [for*="-'+from+'-"]').attr({
            "name" : function(int, input){
                if (input != null){
                    return input.replace('['+from+']', '[' + to + ']');
                }
            },
            "id" : function(int, input){
                if (input != null){
                    return input.replace('-'+from+'-', '-' + to + '-');
                }
            },
            "for" : function(int, input){
                if (input != null){
                    return input.replace('-'+from+'-', '-' + to + '-');
                }
            },
            "value" : ""
        }).end();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#extrainfo-files').on('click', '.extrafile-add', function(){

    // Create the new row
    var $fileList = $('.file-list-extrainfo');
    var $template = $('.extrainfo-file-template').clone();

    var rowId = '-' + (new Date).getTime();
    $template.removeClass('extrainfo-file-template hide').attr('data-id', rowId);

    $template.find('[name*="[0]"], [id*="-0-"], [for*="-0-"]').attr({
                "name" : function(int, input){
                    if (input != null){
                        return input.replace('[0]', '[' + rowId + ']');
                    }
                },
                "id" : function(int, input){
                    if (input != null){
                        return input.replace('-0-', '-' + rowId + '-');
                    }
                },
                "for" : function(int, input){
                    if (input != null){
                        return input.replace('-0-', '-' + rowId + '-');
                    }
                },
                "value" : ""
    }).end();


    $template.appendTo($fileList);

});
```